# Report generation fails

Tags: report, karate

We are trying to use Karate/Gatling for performance tests and very often the run succeeds but the results are not generated with this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot create children while terminating or terminated
        at akka.actor.dungeon.Children.makeChild(Children.scala:270)
```

I can see the simulation logs in `profilessimulation-xxx/simulation.log` folder. When I try to generate the report using `./gatling.sh -ro /simulation.log`, I get this error.

```
>
>
exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "profilessimulation"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Here is part of the simulation.log >>

```
RUN ic.ecx.automation.testcases.profilesSimulation      profilessimulation  1553697537449   null    2.0
USER    test    1   START   1553697537633   1553697537633
USER    test    2   START   1553697537893   1553697537893
USER    test    3   START   1553697537994   1553697537994
USER    test    4   START   1553697538095   1553697538095
USER    test    5   START   1553697538204   1553697538204
USER    test    6   START   1553697538304   1553697538304
USER    test    7   START   1553697538403   1553697538403
USER    test    8   START   1553697538503   1553697538503
USER    test    9   START   1553697538603   1553697538603
USER    test    10  START   1553697538703   1553697538703
REQUEST test    3       GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539459   1553697541977   OK   
REQUEST test    6       GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539460   1553697541977   OK   
REQUEST test    5       GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539460   1553697541977   OK   
REQUEST test    4       GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539460   1553697541977   OK   
REQUEST test    1       GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539459   1553697541977   OK   
REQUEST test    7       GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539459   1553697544333   OK   
REQUEST test    10      GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539460   1553697546110   OK   
REQUEST test    2       GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539459   1553697546120   OK   
REQUEST test    9       GET /ecx/v3/l2/buyer/connections?pageSize=20    1553697539460   1553697546130   OK
```

Any idea how to generate the report from the simulation log?

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you can narrow down this problem and help us replicate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Just a guess, but in case the report is not getting time to be written, I believe Gatling has a concept of `after` hooks: https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_structure/#hooks

So maybe you could add a Thread.sleep in the after hook to make sure Gatling terminates gracefully. If you are using values for [`pauseFor()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#pausefor) try to not have values or use `Nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We did try to add  sleep and still see the issue. Please note, I missed one info in the previous message. For single user for a 1 minute run - no errors and reports generated fine, For 10 users for a 1 minute run  sometimes it errors but simulation.log is getting generated , for 100 users it fails always but simulation.log is getting generated. That was the reson I was trying to find out if we can generate the reports from simulation.log.

Comment: @kCliff not done this at all - but sounds like if you import the simulation.log into excel as a tab-delimited file or equivalent - you will be able to spot (and maybe fix) which rows have un-expected non-numeric data etc. may be worth exploring if this is a known gatling issue. wonder if you get better results on a meatier machine

Comment: will try this - meatier machine :)